# Issue with curly brackets php

Tags: php

I have a registration page to register students, but my page keeps reflecting theres an error with my curly bracket

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3\www\Enrollment_System-www.webdevelopplus.com\enrolsys\registerwrite.php on line 65**

Source

```
<?php   
    $username =$_POST["newname"];
    $password =$_POST["newpass"];
    $cpassword =$_POST["conpass"];
    $firstname =$_POST["firstName"];
    $lastname =$_POST["lastName"];
    $others =$_POST["others"];
    $email =$_POST["email"];
    $phone =$_POST["phone"];
    $sex =$_POST["sex"];
    $bg =$_POST["bg"];
    $genotype =$_POST["genotype"];
    $dob =$_POST["dob"];
    $address =$_POST["address"];
    $state =$_POST["state"];
    $lga =$_POST["lga"];
    $nationality =$_POST["nationality"];
    $sq =$_POST["sq"];
    $sa =$_POST["sa"];
    $time =$_POST["time"];
    $day =$_POST["day"];
?>

<?php

if ($password !==$cpassword){
    echo "<div align='center'><img src='./images/progress_med2.gif'>";
    include ("./error1.php");
    echo "<center>Sorry, but the password you provided did not match.<p><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'<img src='./images/goback.jpg'></a>";
  include("./error2.php");
exit;
}

if (eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$]", $email)){
  echo "<div align='center'><img src='./images/progress_med2.gif'>";
    include ("./error1.php");
    echo "<center>Sorry, but your email address is not valid.<p><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'<img src='./images/goback.jpg'></a>";
  include("./error2.php");
exit;
}
?>

<?php
include("./DB/config.php");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE Username='$username'";
        $results = mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) {
        include("./error1.php");
        echo "<center><img src ='./images/userexist.png'>Sorry, but the .$username. you have chosen is already in existence.<P><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'><img src='./images/goback.jpg'></a>";
        include("./error2.php");
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'";
        $results = mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) {
        include("./error1.php");
        echo "<center><img src ='./images/userexist.png'>Sorry, but the .$email. you have chosen is already in existence.<P><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'><img src='./images/goback.jpg'></a>";
        include("./error2.php");
    } else {    
        $SQL1 = "Insert into members(username,Firstname,Lastname,Others,Email,Phone,Sex,Blood_Group,Genotype,Date_Of_Birth,Address,State,LGA,Nationality,Security_Question,Security_Answer,createTime,createDate) Values ('','$username','$firstname','$lastname','$others','$email','$phone','$sex','$bg','$genotype','$dob','$address','$state','$lga','$nationality','$sq','$sa','$time','$day')";
        $results1 = mysql_query($SQL1) or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location: ./register_preview.php")
    }
       }

?>
```

**How should I align these {}** in my if and else statements?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injections and Cross-Site Scripting.

Comment: Gumbo is right, you've to make sure that you're sanitizing it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the whole code to this;

```
<?php   
    $username =$_POST["newname"];
    $password =$_POST["newpass"];
    $cpassword =$_POST["conpass"];
    $firstname =$_POST["firstName"];
    $lastname =$_POST["lastName"];
    $others =$_POST["others"];
    $email =$_POST["email"];
    $phone =$_POST["phone"];
    $sex =$_POST["sex"];
    $bg =$_POST["bg"];
    $genotype =$_POST["genotype"];
    $dob =$_POST["dob"];
    $address =$_POST["address"];
    $state =$_POST["state"];
    $lga =$_POST["lga"];
    $nationality =$_POST["nationality"];
    $sq =$_POST["sq"];
    $sa =$_POST["sa"];
    $time =$_POST["time"];
    $day =$_POST["day"];
?>

<?php

if ($password !==$cpassword)
{
    echo "<div align='center'><img src='./images/progress_med2.gif'>";
    include ("./error1.php");
    echo "<center>Sorry, but the password you provided did not match.<p><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'<img src='./images/goback.jpg'></a>";
  include("./error2.php");
exit;
}

if (eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$]", $email))
{
  echo "<div align='center'><img src='./images/progress_med2.gif'>";
    include ("./error1.php");
    echo "<center>Sorry, but your email address is not valid.<p><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'<img src='./images/goback.jpg'></a>";
  include("./error2.php");
exit;
}
?>

<?php
include("./DB/config.php");

    if () // define what to check?
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE Username='$username'";
        $results = mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) 
        {
        include("./error1.php");
        echo "<center><img src ='./images/userexist.png'>Sorry, but the .$username. you have chosen is already in existence.<P><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'><img src='./images/goback.jpg'></a>";
        include("./error2.php");
        } 
        else 
        {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'";
        $results = mysql_query($query);

            if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) 
            {
                include("./error1.php");
                echo "<center><img src ='./images/userexist.png'>Sorry, but the .$email. you have chosen is already in existence.<P><a href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)'><img src='./images/goback.jpg'></a>";
                include("./error2.php");
            } 
            else 
            {    
                $SQL1 = "Insert into members(username,Firstname,Lastname,Others,Email,Phone,Sex,Blood_Group,Genotype,Date_Of_Birth,Address,State,LGA,Nationality,Security_Question,Security_Answer,createTime,createDate) Values ('','$username','$firstname','$lastname','$others','$email','$phone','$sex','$bg','$genotype','$dob','$address','$state','$lga','$nationality','$sq','$sa','$time','$day')";
                $results1 = mysql_query($SQL1) or die(mysql_error());
                header("Location: ./register_preview.php")
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Make sure you have defined the variable in if() check

Comment: Removing that last bracket makes your answer wrong. Besides that it's the same as my answer...

Comment: Thanks imran Works now

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an if sentence between these 2 lines

```
include("./DB/config.php");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE Username='$username'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the very last "}".

There is nothing opening that block within those php tags. When it tells you you have an un needed } on line 65, always first try going to line 65 and removing it :)

Also, i think you meant to actaully have an "if" there matching that bracket, since it's indented. Perhaps you accidentally removed it?

The errors are there for a reason.

Comment: No, that last bracket is there for a reason. The formatting isn't good so you can't really see it.